# migrating data of Image type from SQL Server 2005 to a BLOB column in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, migration, oracle10g, informatica

We need help in migrating data of Image type from SQL Server 2005 to a BLOB column in Oracle 10g.

SQL Server 2005 column of image data type contains data for files attached to the system from front end. Files could be xls, jpg, txt etc.
We need this attachment to be displayed in the front end of another application, which uses ORACLE 10g as back end.

We have already tried this using Informatica but the content of the files could not be viewed. But it is able to detect the type of file (xls, jpg, txt etc) but the content is blank. We aren’t sure if any specific option needs to be used while doing Informatica mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a BLOB is just that. A long stream of binary data. There is no meta information detailing what format, if any, that data lives in.

Commonly if a BLOB has been sourced from a file, then the file name will have been recorded in a separate column. In many cases the suffix of the file name indicates the nature of the data. A file ending in ".xls" is PROBABLY an Excel spreadsheet (but you can quite easily rename an image file to end with a .xls). Audio and video files are more complicated matter as, while the suffix may give you an idea, MPG files might use different codecs internally. So a PC may be happy playing some MPGs but not others even if those others play quite happily on another machine.

When you throw a file to a web browser, you send a header line like "Content-Type: application/msword". This suggests to the browser what application should be be used to open a file. The browser takes that suggestion and opens what it thinks is the most appropriate viewer (it might be Adobe Reader for a PDF, but the user and their OS/environment settings might point it to a different reader, such as FoxIt).

I recommend you first transfer some of the files to the OS. Perhaps use a BFILE to write them to an OS file on the server and FTP them across, preferably with the original filename. Then see if the local/client machine can open the file with the appropriate application.

If it can, then the data is clean, and the issue is with the application. You should also be able to use checksums to confirm that the data after migration is the same as the data before migration.